# date format in smarty (months without leading zero)

Tags: smarty

right now, I have a date that is displayed like this:

```
19\06\2013
```

what I want is this :

```
19\6\2013
```

my current smarty code is :

```
 {$variable|date_format:"%e\%m\%Y"}
```

I tried using %n for the month (I assumed that anything that works on php will work in smarty) but it did not give me any result.

How can I display the month without a leading zero in Smarty? is there any workaround solutions? I do not want to edit and format the date in my php file.

Comment: Which smarty version do you use? If you use Smarty 3.x, you can work with the date format instead of the strftime format like so `{$variable|date_format:"d\j\Y"}`

Comment: @sofl your code does not work.. you forgot the % before each letter. And I am using the last stable version of smarty. read the question before answering

Comment: No I don't forgot the `%`. Its only required in strftime format. My example definitely works in Smarty 3.1.13 (latest stable). Check out `modifier.date_format.php` in the smarty plugins dir and then you will realize that BOTH formats are available (since version 3.x). Read the comment before answering.

Comment: it is outputing `djY`for me

Comment: My bad. It actually prints that because the \ is an escape prefix in date format. Does it work this way `{$variable|date_format:'d/n/Y'|replace:'/':'\\'}` ?

Comment: Sofl's code works for me, if i change "\" for for example "."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Today I have the same problem and this works for me…

#### Windows server

This solution seems to work only on windows based servers (localhost in my case).

```
{$variable|date_format:"%d\%#m\%Y"}
```

Just put hash `#` before letter 'm'.

I'm using Smarty v3

#### Linux server:

I moved my project to remote server (probably linux) and hash sign stop to work. I found another solution, just put hyphen `-` before letter 'm':

```
{$variable|date_format:"%d\%-m\%Y"}
```

And this works on linux, but not on windows.

#### Cross-platform PHP-based solution:

But because smarty is a PHP plugin we can use all of PHP functions. So this is another solution I found, maybe not so elegant but it seems to work everywhere.

```
{assign var="dateTime" value=$variable|strtotime}
{*
or shorter:
{$dateTime=$variable|strtotime}
*}
<p>{"j/n/Y"|date:$dateTime}</p>
```

#### Note:

The above solutions work for formatting day with out leading zero also:

```
{$variable|date_format:"%-d vs %d vs %#d"}
```

Comment: Great! why didn't they mention in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

{$variable|date_format:"**j. n. Y**":"":"**any string - not either strftime or auto**"}

then you can write date format as in [php function date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

[smarty_modifier_date_format($string, **$format**=null, $default_date='', **$formatter='auto'**)](https://github.com/opensolutions/smarty/blob/master/plugins/modifier.date_format.php)